# While adding new contentDocumentLink Contentdocuments lastmodifieddate is getting changed. How we can stop that

Tags: contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

I am migrating attachment records to contentVersion. I am also updating created and lastmodified date of new contentversion records from Attachment record. It is getting updated fine. But when I am creating contentDocumentLink records it is also updating the lastmodifieddate on contentDocument record. Is it correct behaviour?
To test this behaviour you can create a file. Then run following code to create a contentDocumentlink

```
ContentDocumentLink conDocumentLink = new ContentDocumentLink(
                                          LinkedEntityId = <AccountId>,
                                          ContentDocumentId = <ContentdocumentID>,
                                          ShareType = 'I',
                                          Visibility = 'AllUsers'
                                      );
insert conDocumentLink;
```

When you ran this code lastmodifieddate on ContentDocument will change.

Comment: How are you migrating attachment to ContentVersion?

Comment: I am using apex for that

Comment: Can you add that part of code as well to the question? I have tried uploading file via ui and insert the contentdocumentlink, but could not reproduce your issue.

Comment: Can you try by refreshing the files tabs. It will show up

Comment: Is this ContentDocumentLink representing the _first_ sharing event for the file?

Comment: Yes I have observed that. If file is shared first time only then its lastmodifieddate is changing

Comment: @DavidReed Regarding you comment "Is this ContentDocumentLink representing the first sharing event for the file?", why would that be relevant? I am also in the same situation, I'm migrating files and their ContentDocumentLinks, and I want to preserve the LastModified in the ContentDocument. However, when creating the ContentDocumentLink, I lose the original LastModifiedDate. Thanks